# MVC3: making a helper aware of a model property's place in the graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, reflection

I have a fairly complex model for one of my pages; it's made of several nested model objects.  In one section that uses a child object with a child collection, I use the `EditorFor` helper like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CAS.LERoles[i].LE, "TinyText")
```

, I will end up with something like:

```
<input id="CAS_LERoles_0__LE" class="tinyText" type="text" value="0" name="CAS.LERoles[0].LE" data-val-required="The Legal Entity field is required." data-val-number="The field Legal Entity must be a number." data-val="true">
```

... this is great.  However, I wrote my own helper to convert enums to select lists, like so:

```
public static HtmlString EnumSelectListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> forExpression,
    object htmlAttributes,
    bool blankFirstLine)
    where TModel : class
    where TProperty : struct
{
    //MS, it its infinite wisdom, does not allow enums as a generic constraint, so we have to check here.
    if (!typeof(TProperty).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("This helper method requires the specified model property to be an enum type.");

    //initialize values
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(forExpression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var propertyName = metaData.PropertyName;
    var propertyValue = htmlHelper.ViewData.Eval(propertyName).ToStringOrEmpty();

    //build the select tag
    var returnText = string.Format("<select id=\"{0}\" name=\"{0}\"", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(propertyName));
    if (htmlAttributes != null)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in htmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(htmlAttributes, null)))
        {
            returnText += string.Format(" {0}=\"{1}\"", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(kvp.Key),
                HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(kvp.Value.ToStringOrEmpty()));
        }
    }
    returnText += ">\n";

    if (blankFirstLine)
    {
        returnText += "<option value=\"\"></option>";
    }

    //build the options tags
    foreach (var enumName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(TProperty)))
    {
        var idValue = ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(TProperty), enumName, true)).ToString();
        var displayValue = enumName;

        // get the corresponding enum field using reflection
        var field = typeof(TProperty).GetField(enumName);
        var display = ((DisplayAttribute[])field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)).FirstOrDefault();
        var titleValue = string.Empty;
        if (display != null)
        {
            // The enum field is decorated with the DisplayAttribute =>
            // use its value
            displayValue = display.Name;
            titleValue = display.Description.ToStringOrEmpty();
        }

        returnText += string.Format("\t<option value=\"{0}\" title=\"{1}\"",
            HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(idValue), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(titleValue));
        if (enumName == propertyValue)
        {
            returnText += " selected=\"selected\"";
        }
        returnText += string.Format(">{0}</option>\n", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(displayValue));
    }

    //close the select tag
    returnText += "</select>\n";
    return new HtmlString(returnText);
}
```

and when I use this in my page like so:

```
@Html.EnumSelectListFor(m => m.CAS.LERoles[i].APMasterRole)
```

I end up with this:

```
<select name="APMasterRole" id="APMasterRole">
(stuff)
</select>
```

In retrospect, I guess I assumed that would be translated appropriately and now I realize I was a bit naive.  I'm really hoping there's a mechanism built into the MVC framework that I can use to generate the proper name and id; otherwise this looks like a maze of reflection.

So the question is, is there a mechanism available to create the name and id strings for a complex model object like this?  If so, how would it be used?  If not, is there a relatively simple way to generate the name and id so that the form data can be bound back to the object model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm really hoping there's a mechanism built into the MVC framework
>   that I can use to generate the proper name and id; otherwise this
>   looks like a maze of reflection.

Of course that there is such mechanism. How do you think the built-in helpers do it? Don't you ever read the source code of the ASP.NET MVC framework? Or use Reflector or something?

```
string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(forExpression);
var ti = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo;
string fullHtmlFieldName = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
string id = ti.GetFullHtmlFieldId(fullHtmlFieldName);
// Now go ahead and use fullHtmlFieldName and id

var returnText = string.Format(
    "<select id=\"{0}\" name=\"{1}\"", 
    id, 
    fullHtmlFieldName
);
```

Ah and before I forget: Please use a `TagBuilder` to generate DOM elements such as `<select>` instead of this horrible string concatenations which doesn't encode properly anything. Not to even mention the `+=`  operator on strings inside a loop. Strings are immutable and this costs you memory allocations! At least use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: ...I think you're sorta joking about reading the source code of the MVC Framework...  I hope you are.  The `TagBuilder` is something I will investigate, though in my defense everything that needs to be encoded is encoded.  Considering the practical size limits on a select box, I don't think the `+=` operations are necessarily a big deal, but yes it could be better.

Comment: No, of course that I am not joking about reading the source code. I can't even imagine how people can develop advanced applications with some framework without knowing how this framework is built and works. I agree that you are encoding everything but why should you be doing this manually? Why reinventing wheels when there are already existing mechanisms built into the framework that aid you in this aspect?

Comment: To be honest I was not aware there were such mechanisms, which is the reason behind the question.  I'm always looking for ways to improve my code, but reading a framework's source code... seems a bit daunting.

Comment: I know, don't worry. That's what Stack Overflow is => to share our knowledge. But we are getting a little off-topic in our chattering here. What gives the code? Is it working?

Comment: The source of .NET, ASP.NET, MVC is free, so yes, download and read it! Source of MVC3 RTM: https://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781

Comment: It's a shame Microsoft's poor documentation quality forces you to read the source code to figure out how to make their stuff work. But at least they made it available.